# My returnURL is not working in production

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-config

I am using RedirectFromLoginPage in my vb.net web app(.net 4).  It works fine in my dev environment, but fails in my production environment.

When I login through dev, I get this URL:

```
http://localhost:63509/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx
```

However, when I push it to production, and login, I get this URL:

```
http://aaa.aaa.edu/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Account/Login.aspx" timeout="300" defaultUrl="yourView.aspx" />
    </authentication>
```

I've verified that my default document on my IIS 7 web server is Default.aspx. I even set it in web.config to make sure.

Is there anything I could do to fix this?
The authorization section of web.config looks like this:

```
    <authorization>
       <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Thanks

Comment: What page do you end up on after a successful login in your production example?

Comment: Assuming that default.aspx is set up as your primary document in a directory then `/` should be the same as `/default.aspx` in terms of where it redirects to so I echo Scrappydog in asking what the actual results are...

Comment: Actually it doesn't go anywhere.  It ends up taking me to a folder listing of everything that is in that folder.

Comment: Even though it takes me no where, it does log me in. Because when I click on any of .aspx files in the folder, it shows me as logged in.

Comment: I think you need to double check your default document config for this site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web.config, what does the  section look like? It should read as follows:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Or, it may be a cookie issue. Are you explicitly setting FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain anywhere? Since you're using a subdomain that could cause an issue. Also, try clearing the cookies in your cache or trying to login via a different browser to see if it's a cookie issue.

Comment: FF, Chrome, and IE all do the same in my production environment.  But they all work in my dev environment.

Comment: Is IIS on the production server set to handle default.aspx as a legit document?

Comment: default.aspx is set as a default document.